# From the Standpoint of the Wireless Network, What Can a Compromised Device Connected to It Cause?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security

Allow me to make it very specific with a hypothetical scenario.

Let's say that I have (unwisely) flashed a mobile phone with a ROM coded by a malicious user. Let's then suppose I connect this device to a wifi network (secured with WPA2).

For our purposes, let's assume the device does not have a SIM card inserted and that I do not use it even more unwisely (say, logging in to Google, providing my passwords). The only thing supplied is the password to the wifi network, and the only usage is to browse random web pages (without logging in to anything).

In this scenario, what is the limit of security risk caused by this behavior?

For example, I suppose the malicious coder might have access to the network traffic going through the device itself (pages I might browse on the device's browser, for instance), is that right?

I'm more interested, however, knowing what kind of damage can happen *outside* the device itself. Are, for instance, other devices connected to the same wifi network at risk? Is it possible for the malicious coder to access the router admin page settings (provided the password is different)? And, for instance, is it possible for the malicious coder to know my IP address and even spoof it for other malicious purposes (i.e. perform unlawful acts online making it seem it was me performing them)?

Answer (score 0):

A malicious device on a basic Ethernet LAN (including wireless Ethernet a.k.a. Wi-Fi) can perform an ARP spoofing/poisoning attack that can cause any and all of the network's traffic to go through the malicious device. This allows the malicious device to snoop on the traffic and possibly block it or modify it (especially traffic that is not encrypted at a higher level; for example, plain HTTP vs. HTTPS). This can allow it to do "man in the middle" attacks that further exploit security weaknesses.

And yes, it can generate malicious traffic that looks like it is coming from the other devices.

Comment: Isn't the repercussion of this that _any_ public network (that is, even if they're locked) are inherently unsafe? If, say, a public library offers WiFi to their clients, to whom it provides the password, isn't possible that one malicious client can connect to the network and compromise any and all other devices that use it?